# PG:GroupingError only appearing on production

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, inner-join

I have a model "Playlist" which has_many and belongs_to another model "User", through an intermediary model "PlaylistUser".

I have code that, for a given Playlist `@playlist`, lists all the other Playlists that share a User with `@playlist`, ordered by how many they share.

This code works perfectly on development, but on production, it's throwing this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "playlists.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" INNER JOIN "playlist...
           ^
: SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" INNER JOIN "playlist_users" ON "playlist_users"."playlist_id" = "playlists"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "playlist_users"."user_id" WHERE (NOT (playlists.id = 30 OR playlists.id = 41)) AND "users"."id" IN (45, 89, 71, 117, 115, 173, 177, 180, 161, 220, 223, 199, 221, 239, 204, 205, 206, 207, 211, 261, 282, 284, 286, 251, 252, 255, 310, 311, 315, 318, 307, 362, 319, 306, 289, 316, 305, 321, 322, 330, 333, 292, 294, 304, 300, 340, 341, 342, 343, 405, 406, 410, 408, 409, 407, 413, 416, 417, 418, 425, 427, 392, 401, 403, 445, 446, 449, 450, 379, 456, 451, 454, 459, 437, 442, 444, 496, 501, 518, 548, 549, 533, 553, 1112, 1113, 1459, 455, 348, 1458, 242, 1275, 151, 1890, 336, 203, 404, 166, 453, 114, 157, 285, 448, 447, 443, 550, 2167, 2168, 287, 320, 293, 65, 2098, 2097, 2099, 387, 3, 2175, 2170, 2174, 2182, 2171, 438, 2180, 2181, 2169, 2176, 347, 2429, 2177, 2445, 2178, 2447, 58, 2480, 390, 452, 554, 555, 313, 92, 275, 335, 428, 167, 302, 2173, 1538) GROUP BY playlists.id  ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Why would my query be working on development but not on production?

**Query**

```
@playlist_ids = @playlist.user_ids
@more_playlists = Playlist.joins(:users).where.not('playlists.id = ? OR playlists.id = ?', 30, 41).where(users: {id: @playlist_ids}).group('playlists.id').order('count(*) desc')
```

**Assocations:**

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :users, :through => :playlist_users
end

class PlaylistUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_users
end
```

---

### **UPDATE**

This is pretty strange, I added Playlist.name to the GROUP BY as per trincot's suggestion:

```
@playlist_ids = @playlist.user_ids
Playlist.select('playlists.id, playlists.name')
    .joins(:playlist_users)
    .where('playlists.id NOT IN (30, 41)')
    .where(playlist_users: {user_id: @playlist_ids})
    .group('playlists.id, playlists.name')
    .order('count(*) desc')
```

But I'm getting back a similar error, except now it's telling me I have to include the`Playlist` attribute `subject_id` in the GROUP BY clause:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "playlists.subject_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

But I didn't reference `subject_id` literally anywhere in my query, or even in the model, controller, or view for the page. Why on earth would that column even be involved in this?

Comment: what did you want to achieve with the `group by`? You should just leave it out.

Comment: Are you using exactly the same database in production as development?

Comment: Group by clause expects all of the columns in select clause to be given in Group by clause. So instead of using *, specify the appropriate column names and include them in Group by clause to avoid this issue

Comment: @trincot The query doesn't work without the group.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Do you mean the actual data, or the database type/version?

Comment: @PK20 How exactly would I accomplish that?

Comment: something like `select col1, col2, col3 from table group by col1, col2, col3 order by count(*)`

Comment: I meant the DBMS and associated config rather than the data.  However, if you get a db error in production and not dev, copying the data from the production db to the dev db is also often useful for replicating the problem locally.

Comment: @PK20 How could I turn that into a rails query?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I just checked, on production I'm using psql 8.4, and on dev I'm using psql 9.4. So that probably explains it.

Comment: Possibly...you now have to decide whether to upgrade production or downgrade dev!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is not valid according to the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to 
>   ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions, since there would be more than one 
>   possible value to return for an ungrouped column.

If you say it works in your development environment, it must mean that environment has another database engine (version) running.

You should use a statement like this, where the list of fields in the `SELECT` clause is the same as the list given in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT      playlists.id,  playlists.name, ...
FROM        playlists 
INNER JOIN  playlist_users ON playlist_users.playlist_id = playlists.id 
WHERE       playlists.id NOT IN (30, 41) 
AND         playlist_users.user_id IN (your_long_list_comes_here) 
GROUP BY    playlists.id,  playlists.name, ...
ORDER BY    count(*) desc
```

Note that you don't actually need to join the *users* table for the result of your interest, so I removed it and replaced the test on *user_id* accordingly. Also, the condition on the playlists.id is expressed more concise using the `IN` operator.

The corresponding Active Record query would be:

```
Playlist.joins(:playlist_users)
    .where('playlists.id NOT IN (30, 41)')
    .where(playlist_users: {user_id: @playlist_ids})
    .select('playlists.id, playlists.name')
    .group('playlists.id, playlists.name')
    .order('count(*) desc')
```

You have to add any other fields you need in both the `select` and `group` arguments.

Comment: How would I translate this query into rails?

Comment: I tried that query, but now it's telling me that `@playlist.subject_id` needs to be included in the GROUP BY clause, even though I made no mention of `subject_id` anywhere on the page. I updated my question.

Comment: Try to move the select method after the joins method in the chain. Or try  this `select ([:id, :name])` instead